Connection refuse when using command "Cypher-shell" in Neo4j
I tried to install neo4j in ubuntu. This is how I deployed. But when i use the command cypher-shell, I get the error "Connection refused".
I started the neo4j service:

And got this error:

Can you help me to resolve this issues. Thanks for reading.

It does not look like you used the command cypher-shell -a 'neo4j://<neo4j-ip-address>:7687', where  would be replaced by the IP address of the neo4j server.

how can i get neo4j-ip-address

It mean ip address of server?

Actually, since you seem to be running on same machine, see my answer below.

Since you seem to be running cypher-shell from the same machine that neo4j is running on, you probably just need to provide the username and password. For example:
cypher-shell -u <username> -p <password>

See the docs for more details.
